# Magento 2: Call frontend template inside phtml

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

This code below is used to call the template from /app/code/ module.

```
    $gridHtml = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(
        '\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template',
        'custom_grid_new'
    )->setTemplate('Magento_CustomGrid::product/view/templates/grid.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
```

How to set the template from following path

```
/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Custom_Grid/templates/grid1.phtml
```

tried this above in above code, but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

That path you are using `/app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/Custom_Grid/templates/grid1.phtml` makes it look as if you have just put your code insde the Magento Codebase.

You should **never** do that. Either extend `luma-theme` with `your-theme` and put your code there, or create your own module and extend the active theme via module.

With the "Theme option" you can call your templates directly.

With the "Module option" you can put your `grid1.phtml` in `YourVendor/YourModule/area/templates/grid1.phtml` while `area` is either `frontend` or `adminhtml` and call it like this:

```
->setTemplate('YourVendor_YourModule::grid1.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Please refer to Magento 2 official documentation for theme inheritance.

Comment: Thanks but i found solution for that answered by someone in magento community! adding as answer

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-Call-phtml-path-from-frontend-folder/m-p/463320/thread-id/12091#M12094

```
$gridHtml = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(
'\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template',
'custom_grid_new'
)->setTemplate('Magento_CustomGrid::grid.phtml')
->toHtml();
```